# Trying to override Django User model username validation

Tags: django, django-1.10

I am trying to override the django default User model username field to allow hashtags in usernames.

I know the model itself will let me do this but the standard form registration doesn't seem to allow it. I'm using django-allauth as well.

How do I replace the regex in the default User model form to allow a hashtag in the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django-allauth has a lot of configuration, one of its options is set the validators for username

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_VALIDATORS
```

for a better reference you can check https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

The `ACCOUNT_USERNAME_VALIDATORS` accept a list of paths of custom username validators. So, you can define something like:

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_VALIDATORS = ('myproject.myapp.validators.custom_username_validators')
```

and in the specified path `'myproject.myapp.validators.CustomUsernameValidtor'` you must define a validator class like:

```
import re
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

@deconstructible
class CustomUsernameValidator(object):
    message = _('Invalid username')

    def __call__(self, value):
        if not re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_@#-]+', value)
            raise DjangoValidationError(self.message, code='invalid_username')
```

Hope this can help you.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

This gets me a little further, but I think I may have hit a bug in allauth. If I set my account_username_validator to be just like what you have up there (formatted for my code of course), I get an error saying account_username_validator is expected to be a list. If I make it a list, I get an assert error because that check isn't looking for only strings.

Comment: Oh! I see it. Good find! It supposed is has been fixed but I imagine that it hasn't been deployed. You also can define you own custom user model and use the attribute validators of CharField.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I was actually hitting a bug in the software.

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/pull/1648

For anyone else that happens by.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to Javier's Fix, your validators file should look like this:

```
import re
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

@deconstructible
class CustomUsernameValidator(object):
    message = _('Invalid username')

    def __call__(self, value):
        if not re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_@#-]+', value):
            raise ValidationError(self.message, code='invalid_username')


custom_usename_validator = [CustomUsernameValidator()]
```

And your settings.py file:

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_VALIDATORS = 'mypath.to.validators.custom_usename_validator'
```