# How can I allow spaces in the default django user model username?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-users

I am trying to allow spaces in the django user model, I tried overwriting its validator and it still does not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the code you have tried, along with the complete text of any errors or tracebacks (run with `DEBUG=True` to capture them). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE).

Comment: It was in an older project, and there were no errors that username worked just fine but it did not allow spaces

Answer (score 1):

The django username validator is written like this

```
@deconstructible
class UnicodeUsernameValidator(validators.RegexValidator):
    regex = r'^[\w.@+-]+$'
    message = _(
        'Enter a valid username. This value may contain only letters, '
        'numbers, and @/./+/-/_ characters.'
    )
    flags = 0
```

and hence it doesn't allow any space characters.

This might help you to create a custom user model:

https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/

Comment: So, is it impossible to overwrite regex of the validator ?

Comment: I am actually thinking about writing a custom user model but the reset password view is what preventing me, I do not know how to create one.

Comment: Was this of any help? "Trying to override Django User model username validation - Stack Overflow" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106049/trying-to-override-django-user-model-username-validation